# Using Ito Isometry to find the mean and variance of an Ito Stochastic Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have almost completed a question which is to find the mean and variance of the following:

$I_T = \int_0^T \sqrt{|W_t|}d W_t$

In order to do this, I know I need to find $\mathbb E [I_T]$ and $\mathbb E [I_T^2]$

For $\mathbb E [I_T]$, I have used the fact that $M_T$ is a martingale where $M_T = \int_0^T \sqrt{|W_t|}d W_t$, based on the properties of martingales we know that $ \mathbb E [M_t]= \mathbb E[M_0]=0 $ which is the mean.

Then I need to find the variance which is a bit more tricky, so I have used Ito Isometry: $var(I_T) = \mathbb E (I_T^2)- \mathbb E (I_T)^2 = \mathbb E [\int^T_0 |W_t|dt] $.

The part of this I need help with is to actually find a value for the variance, is it possible to simplify what I have so far and how?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Apply Fubini's theorem and use that $W_t$ is Gaussian with mean zero and variance $t$. (Look up/Calculate $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ for $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.) Re your calculation: It should read $\mathbb{E}(\int_0^T |W_t| \, dt)$ (i.e. $|W_t|$ instead of $|W_T|$ under the integral.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$W_t \sim N(0,t),$ so

\begin{align*}
E|W_t| &= \int^{\infty}_{- \infty}|x| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}}dx     \\
&=  \int^{\infty}_{0}2x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}}dx \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}}.
\end{align*}
So 
$$var(I_T)= \int_0^T \sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}} dt$$